# Java invalid array size

Tags: java, string

I taking a string input from `console`. If I input "abcd" and spilt like this way

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String[]stringInput = input.nextLine().toLowerCase().trim().split("");
```

Suppose, I have entered `"abcd"` as input, `stringInput.length` is showing `5`. But, It should be `4` right ? What's wrong, I am doing here ? Any idea ? How can I solve that ?

Comment: String.split() is really not the method you should use to get individual characters out of a String. Use charAt() or substring() or toCharArray().

Comment: Read about working of method split, u will get your answer......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it using regex in split method as follows:

```
split("(?!^)")
```

[See more details on regex usage.](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html#regex_negative)

Answer (score 2):

There is an empty String at the end.

Use [`split("", -1)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)

> ...., the array can have any length, **and trailing empty strings will be discarded**

Answer (score 1):

Using `split("")` there always be an extra empty element of array at the **first** index

to be sure, you can try:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(stringInput));
```

Output:

```
[, a, b, c, d]
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an empty space always after a string.So you need to use 
in your case `abcd` and a space

```
Use split("", -1)
```